# How can i configure iptables policies with docker to block externals ip

Tags: docker, iptables

I am trying to restrict access to containers from external IP. I followed docker documentation at https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/ but it not working.

I have created a bridge network:

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 172.19.0.0/24 --opt com.docker.network.bridge.name=br-mynet mynet
```

Then I run container trought Docker-compose with previous network. Atfer than i can see iptables rules:

```
~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.2           tcp dpt:postgresql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.3           tcp dpt:omniorb
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.3           tcp dpt:8086
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.6           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.7           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.9           tcp dpt:8888
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.12          tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.8           tcp dpt:3000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.5           tcp dpt:9092
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.4           tcp dpt:http-alt

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

At this step all external IP can connect to all host containers at 172.19.0.x. Then I apply docker rules as described in documentation to accept connection only from 10.223.20.173 :

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i br-mynet ! -s 10.223.20.173 -j DROP
```

That would means the only external 10.223.20.173 can connect to containers. The iptables rules becomes:

```
~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.2           tcp dpt:postgresql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.3           tcp dpt:omniorb
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.3           tcp dpt:8086
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.6           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.7           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.9           tcp dpt:8888
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.12          tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.8           tcp dpt:3000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.5           tcp dpt:9092
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.4           tcp dpt:http-alt

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  -- !10.223.20.173        anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

But with this configuration the ip 10.223.20.173 can't connect to container.
On the over hand, when i apply the rules without the negative symbol !, that ip connect successful. But it should be the other way around.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happens is the following. You have a "box" with an interface connected to the external network, say eth0, and your interface to the docker network, br-mynet:

```
                +---------------------------+
[internet]<---> | (eth0) <-> (br-mynet)     |
                |                ⇵          |
                |            [docker hosts] |
                +---------------------------+
```

You are trying to block packets coming from internet to docker host, from left to right in the image.
They are entering eth0 and forwarded to br-mynet.

You are adding a rule that matches:

- source ! 10.223.20.173
- **incoming interface**: br-mynet

So you are actually matching packets coming from docker with any source address different than 10.223.20.173 (that as, any packet), and are blocking these responses.

Please try:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -o br-mynet ! -s 10.223.20.173 -j DROP
```